# What is the correct way to mysqldump functions to import into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I followed this link, but the functions still wouldn't import into my test database.

http://www.ducea.com/2007/07/25/dumping-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-and-triggers/

What is the correct way of doing it? I also thought I did a whole database dump a while back and they didn't make it into the test database then either.

This is the command I used for just the functions:

`mysqldump --routines=true --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt --skip-triggers db > outputfile.sql -u dev -p`

EDIT:

Looking at the dump file, I am not seeing anything that looks like the functions (there are only four and they have "token" in the name).

```
-- mySQL dump 10.14  Distrib 5.5.50-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: db
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.5.50-MariaDB
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'db'
--
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-08-24 16:29:45
```

So that would explain that. Any reason why they wouldn't be in there based on the command?

Also, what I am using to import:

`sudo mysql test_db < outputfile.sql -u dev -p`

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that command. Did you check the file? Does it contain the routines? Apart from the export command, there is another reason that the import into your test database would not work: an incorrect import command. So maybe add that part too.

Comment: Good call... updated.

Comment: I don't see where `true` is necessary to add with: `--routines=true` in the documentation??  I wonder if that might make it an unknown parameter, and might be why there is no output. Try this command instead: `mysqldump --routines --no-create-info --no-data --no-create-db --skip-opt --skip-triggers db > outputfile.sql -u dev -p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible reason would be that the user `dev` has some privileges on `db` (enough not to throw an error when `mysqldump` attempts to connect to it), but does not have `SELECT ON mysql.proc` which is needed to fetch function definitions. Try to run

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc to dev@localhost
```

(or whichever host `dev` is defined with, instead of `localhost`).

Comment: And `SHOW GRANTS FOR dev@localhost;`